# EmberJS - Computed on async relationships

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, relationship

How can I use computed to monitor async loaded relationships?

In the following example, I would expect the parent title to be displayed as soon as it's loaded into the store.

https://emberjs.jsbin.com/yakofaxazu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for computed props.

Just use below in template :

```
<li>Item: {{item.title}}, Parent: {{item.parent.title}}</li>
```

And also the `parent` relationship should be `async: true`